# Force view controller to reload to refresh UIAppearance changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have been searching for quite a while and can't find an answer. I am working on an iOS app and have a modal settings page that appears on the tap of a button and returns with a segue.
One of the options I would like to implement is a color scheme setting. I really want to avoid manually changing the color for every element on the page.

Apple has a [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol for this sort of thing (so I can set the text color of all buttons, etc.
Their documentation says:

> Note: iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

My question is how to do this. I have tried calling viewWillAppear and setNeedsDisplay without luck.

Comment: remove the view from the view hierarchy - The only way is to [view removeFromSuperView] or if the view is pushed then you can pop the view and push it again without animation

Comment: This is possible without re-adding views to the hierarchy by tracking invocations and replaying them. See this repo: (disclaimer, I'm the author): https://github.com/datwelk/RDRAppearance

Answer (score 24):

Try to use this snippet :

```
NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
    for (UIView *view in window.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [window addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

http://snipplr.com/view/75259/refresh-uiappearance-after-application-loaded/

It works perfect for me after changing app theme using UIAppearance

Comment: This works for me as well but really seems like a 'sledgehammer to crack a nut' solution. I think I might be better off just avoiding UIAppearance if this is what it takes - my use would be a bit more frequent than the occasional theme change.

Comment: Yeah, UIAppearance if for no changes/occasional UI change. If you need to frequently update the UI you need to write your own theming code.

Comment: Worked! Is it memory efficient?

Comment: It's not the best and not the worst. But I didn't find another way to achieve it

Answer (score 15):

Please note that the top answer will have adverse effects on your system keyboard behavior.

It turns out that iOS creates a new system window with `UITextEffectsWindow` class under the hood whenever the keyboard is displayed. If you remove it, your keyboard behavior may be negatively affected. For example, the input accessory views will be detached from the keyboard and will not be visible, except for brief flashes in the navigation controllers.

You can workaround this issue by using an additional check, like so:

```
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
    // Whenever a system keyboard is shown, a special internal window is created in application
    // window list of type UITextEffectsWindow. This kind of window cannot be safely removed without
    // having an adverse effect on keyboard behavior. For example, an input accessory view is
    // disconnected from the keyboard. Therefore, a check for this class is needed. In case this class
    // that is indernal is removed from the iOS SDK in future, there is a "fallback" class check on
    // NSString class that always fails.
    if !window.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UITextEffectsWindow") ?? NSString.classForCoder()) {
        window.subviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
            window.addSubview($0)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `UITextEffectsWindow` is internal and may change in the future. This is why I do not unwrap the variable using `!` but provide a fallback negative `NSString` class instead (no type of window is of `NSString` class).

*Note: For simple apps, you can probably live by using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` for the workaround.*

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Would probably have never figured out why my UIToolbar was disappearing from the keyboard after a theme change.

Comment: I think UIApplication.shared.keyWindow should be the main answer, because most apps should contain only one window. Why would anyone create additional windows in an iOS app? Nonsense.

Comment: @m8labs You do not create an additional window - the iOS automatically creates the second window for you whenever the keyboard is presented in UI. It is an implementation technicality of an iOS operating system that you need to know when manipulating the UI hierarchy.

Answer (score 8):

Specifically, to get the current view and it's superview, try:

```
UIView *currentview = self.window.rootViewController.view;
UIView *superview = currentview.superview;
[currentview removeFromSuperview];
[superview addSubview:currentview];
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift:

```
let windows = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows
for window in windows {
    for view in window.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        window.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3.0.2:

```
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
    for view in window.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        window.addSubview(view)
    }
    // update the status bar if you change the appearance of it.
    window.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a **Swift 5** one-liner:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { $0.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview(); self.window?.addSubview($0) }}
```

Comment: it works fine but it effects keyboard behavour (crashes when open keyboard), i would suggest to see below answer, its fine for all scenarios

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[self.yourView removeFromSuperView];
[self addSubView:yourView];
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to do this from my view controller class, what do I call addSubView on? There is no method with that name under self, and I can't add it back to self.view.

Answer (score 1):

For swift 4:

```
let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
for window in windows {
    for view in window.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        window.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working out for me. I have to call again: `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = ...` and `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(..., for: .normal)` - Surprisingly, only the navigation bar title appearance changes not the bar button items?! They remain unchanged? This is on iOS 11

Comment: @AhmedKhedr, yes but i dont think it is the issue in your case.
I think the issue is with your appearance config.
You can show your code and i will take a look at it, this is my example :

            UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).textColor = .white
let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
        for window in windows {
            for view in window.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                window.addSubview(view)
            }
        }

Comment: Here... https://gist.github.com/aakhedr/a485e008ee2202ae741bb5cfddb77674

Comment: @AhmedKhedr my code work fine in bot of them.
Try putting the  func appearances() inside the func setupProxies() and lets see if it is working

Comment: The UIBarButtonItems including back buttons need to be reset otherwise they get redrawn only in the next drawing cycle - this is in iOS11

Comment: Same for UISegmentedControls - obviously anything whose superclass is UIBarItem - why? No idea! Maybe somebody else can explain...

Comment: @AhmedKhedr call the   setupProxies() before  let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows.

Comment: @AhmedKhedr do you wanna show me the complete  code?

Comment: It’s the gist - This is all of it

Comment: @AhmedKhedr cant work with this code...
what are this fonts?

Comment: Here is a link to a sample project on GitHub https://github.com/aakhedr/BarButtonItem

Comment: @AhmedKhedr and ironRoei I have the same issue, is there any update??

Comment: @KosratD.Ahmad nothing... Even Apple bug reporting and technical support did not respond on this issue...

Comment: Thanks @AhmedKhedr, I just resolved by reasigning root controller view like that ===> if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
            window.rootViewController = TabNavigationController()
            let tab = window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
            tab?.selectedIndex = 3
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

Answer (score 0):

The most answers are very good and perfect for changing language from **LTR** to **RTL** but sometimes ***tab bar navigation titles*** and ***navigation bar titles*** will not get translated. I fixed the problem with the following code

```
if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
    window.rootViewController = TabNavigationController()
    let tab = window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    tab?.selectedIndex = 3
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*Objective c*

> self.view.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleDark;

I use this code if I want change *overrideUserInterfaceStyle* in all view controllers

Comment: Hi :) , could you add a little more explanation, to support your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Of course. I use this code if I want change overrideUserInterfaceStyle in all view controllers.